# Will a SaaS service get penalized if user sends bulk unsolicited emails from connected email account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, email, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

John subscribes to a SaaS service and signs in via OAuth with **John@someemail.com**. John authorizes the SaaS service to send emails on his behalf.

John then sends bulk unsolicited spam emails using the SaaS service.
My question:-

1. Can email servers (which john is sending email to) know which SaaS service is sending the emails on behalf of john@someemail.com?
2. If so, will the SaaS service be penalized by email servers? As in by assuming all emails from the SaaS Service  as 'Spam'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can email servers (which john is sending email to) know which SaaS
> service is sending the emails on behalf of john@someemail.com?

Yes, the SaaS service is using an email server to send the emails, and that email server will be flagged as sending spam.

> If so, will the SaaS service be penalized by email servers? As in by
> assuming all emails from the SaaS Service as 'Spam'?

Yes, the email server's IP or domain name could eventually be added to spam lists that cause all mail from that server to be blocked. If you're using a managed email service like Amazon SES then Amazon themselves may penalize you by reducing your SES sending limits or totally disabling your SES access.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So in sum, the ban will be initiated by 'someemail.com'.

Comment: Someone will flag the email as spam. That will go up to their email server. From there the server that sent the email may eventually be banned, or the entire domain name may be banned, or the service that you are using to send emails may ban you for using them inappropriately.